How to nest <a> inside <a>?
I'm using Svelte 5.
<a href="my-first-link">
    <div>
        <!-- Some elements -->
    </div>
    <a href="my-second-link">
        <div>
            <!-- Some other elements -->
        </div>
    </a>
    <div>
        <!-- Some elements -->
    </div>
</a>

Svelte is throwing a lint error:
`<a>` is invalid inside `<a>`svelte(node_invalid_placement)

What is expected in this situation to fix this issue?

X/Y question. Why would you want to nest links?

I would like an entire element to be a link (ex: a long text or a card), and inside this one element, I need a sub element to be another link

That's expected. You can't have interactive content inside an <a> tag. Since <a> tags are interactive elements themself, you can't nest them. You'll have to redesign your markup to account for this.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactive-content

I understand that this is the spec, but it's still immensely frustrating for use cases like this. In order to fix it, I have to do an absolute ton of refactoring, and the usability of my components will almost certainly decrease compared to what I could do in Svelte 4

It is not possible to stack  elements inside of each other directly in Svelte. You must reorganize your structure so that every link is independent in order to fix the lint mistake. This is one method of code refactoring:
<a href="my-first-link">
    <div>
        <!-- Some elements -->
    </div>
</a>
<a href="my-second-link">
    <div>
        <!-- Some other elements -->
    </div>
</a>
<div>
    <!-- Some elements -->
</div>

To avoid the invalid nesting, move the second  tag outside of the first one. Now, every link can function independently.

Make sure to not have whitespace between the links if you want to make sure the whole thing is a link. Also have a { display:inline-block } on the link elements; use a class to distinguish these links from ohter links
